# Strange behaviour of sharedpreference use

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to recover some images from a server through their url and load all of them in a listview, using adapter and AsyncTask class.
The full urls are stored in a sharedpreference var. So, when i try to recover each image, when i use the sentence to read the url in the sharedpreference var using a concatenate sentence like this one:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    String cadenaURL="";
    String sp = sharedPreferences.getString("url"+position, "");
    if (sp != "")
        cadenaURL = "http://www.domain.com/imagenes/" + sp;
```

then the value of the cadenaURL each time is looping the listview is something like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/imagenes/http://www.domain.com/imagenes/87f67d7a-ac18-48bf-bb37-5c21eaab440e.jpg
```

and so on with the rest of the urls. Is because of this when i try to display the images through imageview controls, this controls are returning error because they cannot resolve the url due an incorrect sintax.

Could you please help me with this issue?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please check what is value of your shared preference?

Comment: what u wanna check with this if `(sp != "")`? use `sp.equal` function instead

Comment: "The full urls are stored in a sharedpreference var." - If this is the case, then you don't need to prepend `"http://www.domain.com/imagenes/"`.

Comment: Even better would be !TextUtils.isEmpty(sp), but the answer below is probably correct.  How many items are you trying to store in this fashion?  There's probably a better solution.

Comment: `!TextUtils.isEmpty()`, extra `s` in there :)

Comment: I'm glad i see you are using the code i proposed two days ago. But you could have stayed with that post and have said that you were going to use my code. Don't run away like that. No need to start yet a post. Maybe you forgot to realise that if you want to extract urls with `getString("url"+position);` that you should have put them in before with someting like `putString("url"+position, url);`. Now did you? And how?

Comment: But ofcourse Mike M. did already tell the solution.

Comment: Sorry, in the sharedpreference var I have the name of the file image. Is because of this that i a append the URL domain with the file name image.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value you stored in shared preferences already includes the `http://www.domain.com/imagenes/` portion of the urls. Try to either save the suffix of the url to shared preferences only (rather than the String `sp`, which I assume is what is happening right now), or avoid adding the `http://www.domain.com/imagenes/` to the beginning of the values you extract from shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the sharedpreference variable store the full url so i reappend the url string with a full url string so there is a full duplicate url string.